# Embeded Rumble video won't fill player

Tags: css, video

I'm trying to embed Rumble videos into my site dynamically, that part is working great. However, I can not get the video to take up the full space available unless I specify the width and height of the iframe itself. I have it set to

```
max-width:1000px;width:100%;height:auto;margin:auto;
```

and the player itself takes up the full width as it should but, the video stays small. Nothing I do seem to work... Any Ideas?

[image: text]
<sub>(source: [thewoodlands.biz](https://thewoodlands.biz/images/rumble-ss.png))</sub>

Answer (score -3):

Found a solution that worked. Just replace the asp classic code in the src string with whatever. Enjoy!

```
<style>
  .videoWrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
    height: 0;
  }
  .videoWrapper iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>

<div class="videoWrapper"><iframe src="<%= url-link %>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
```

Comment: I'm guessing all the downvotes are because you didn't explain anything about your solution. Posting code is definitely recommended, but on these forums you are encouraged to write answers as if you are teaching others. You have taught nothing here. To put it differently, this answer shows a blatantant disregard for helping others. That is frowned upon on SO.

Comment: If you can't accept constructive criticism meant to help you become a better programmer and a better human being, without taking offense, than you may be looking for Reddit. This forum is for programmers and developers who are actively trying to better themselves. The answers provided should give steps that anyone in the future can follow, while also answering the OP's question.

Comment: Oh, I see, you consider this to be "constructive criticism" My bad, most normal people refer to it as trolling. I'm going to ask you politely, please do both of us a favor and move on and have a blessed day!